# Appending class to existing .div's using a function

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I'm running into one more issue so I figured I'd just post the full function.  In this case the function is passed as JSON associative array with arrays "waferId" "detailWafer" and "htmlData" embedded.  I have been able to attached the waferId info and am still having the trouble assigning the htmlData keys as classes (even with changes recommended) AND I can not get the detailWafer x and y data to bind correctly.  From the look of the values, after it performs xScale and yScale the values come out all in one place that roughly corresponds to where 0 would be for both x and y.  When I look at the x and y values in the JSON (in Firebug) they are not zero.  I'm not sure if passing them as +d.y and +d.x is enough to force them as integers, perhaps that is my issue?

```
function buildSlides(data) {
//Constants
var squareSide = 400;
var triangleWidth = 6;
var wafer_center_x = 150027042;
var wafer_center_y = 150187625;
var wafer_scale = 1000000;

//Triangle data
var triangleData = [
    {"x":squareSide / 2 - triangleWidth / 2, "y":squareSide},
    {"x":squareSide / 2, "y":squareSide - triangleWidth},
    {"x":squareSide / 2 + triangleWidth / 2, "y":squareSide},
    {"x":squareSide / 2 - triangleWidth / 2, "y":squareSide}
];
//Create x and y scale
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-wafer_center_x ,wafer_center_x])
    .range([0, squareSide]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-wafer_center_y,wafer_center_y])
    .range([squareSide,0]);

//line function for triangle path
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {return d.x;})
    .y(function(d) {return d.y;})
    .interpolate("linear");

//begin building bootstrap courousel stack
var slides = d3.select(".carousel-inner").selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class","item")
    .attr("id",function(data) {return data.waferId;})
    .append("div")
    .attr("class","container-fluid")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class","row");

//Make the first slide the active slide
d3.selectAll(".item").classed('active', function(d, i) { return i == 0; });

//Build the image side of the slide
var imageSide = slides.append("div")
    .attr("class","col-lg-6 wafer-and-pareto");

//Build the html side of the slide
var htmlSide = slides.append("div")
    .attr("class","col-lg-6 wafer-info");

//Build final location for div that holds svg waferMap
var waferBox = imageSide.append("div")
    .attr("class","row")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class","col-lg-12")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class","wafer-box")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("class","waferMap")
    .attr("width", squareSide)
    .attr("height",squareSide);

//Add the triangle at the bottom
var triangle = waferBox.append("path")
    .attr("d",lineFunction(triangleData))
    .attr("stroke","gray")
    .attr("stroke-width",1)
    .attr("fill","black");

//Draw a round wafer
var wafer = waferBox.append("ellipse")
    .attr("cx",xScale(wafer_center_x / wafer_scale))
    .attr("rx",xScale(wafer_center_x / wafer_scale))
    .attr("cy",yScale(wafer_center_y / wafer_scale))
    .attr("ry",yScale(wafer_center_y / wafer_scale))
    .attr("fill","none")
    .attr("stroke","gray")
    .attr("stroke-width",1);

//Add data points to wafer map
var circle = waferBox.selectAll("circle")
    .data(function(data) {return data.detailWafer;})
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return xScale(+d.x);})
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return yScale(+d.y);})
    .attr("r",1);

//build final location for div that will hold the histogram
var paretoBox = imageSide.append("div")
    .attr("class","row")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class","col-lg-12")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class","pareto-box")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("class","chart");

//Add data to the html side
var waferLabels = htmlSide.append("div")
    .attr("class","col-lg-6");

var labelList = waferLabels.selectAll("div")
    .data(function(data){return d3.keys(data.htmlData);})
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class","htmlLabel")
    .text(function(d){return d;});

var waferValues = htmlSide.append("div")
    .attr("class","col-lg-6");

var waferList = waferValues.selectAll("div")
    .data(function(data) {return d3.values(data.htmlData);})
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class","htmlValue")
    .text(function(data){return data;});

var classes = {};

d3.keys(data.htmlData).forEach(function(d) {
    classes[d] = true;
});

d3.selectAll(".htmlValue")
    .data(function(data) {return d3.keys(data.htmlData);})
    .enter()
    .classed(classes);
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm missing.  I added the following after the waferList variable

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#classed):

> If you want to set several classes at once, use an object literal like so:  selection.classed({'foo': true, 'bar': false}).

In your case, this would look something like this.

```
var classes = {};
d3.keys(data.htmlData).forEach(function(d) {
  classes[d] = true;
});

d3.selectAll(".htmlValue")
  .data(function(data) {return d3.keys(data.htmlData);})
  .enter()
  .classed(classes);
```

Answer (score 0):

With further investigation I discovered that my JSON array was off in values by a factor of 1000, that is the reason my scales were coming back near 0.

For adding the labels as classes, I could not get the solution to work but I decided that I didn't really need it to be a class so instead I bound it as a custom data attribute per the following:

```
 var waferList = waferValues.selectAll("div")
    .data(function(data) {return d3.values(data.htmlData);})
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class","htmlValue")
    .text(function(data){return data;})
    .data(function(data){return d3.keys(data.htmlData)})
    .attr("data-htmlLabel",function(data){return data});
```